# How do I take Moscow as Germany, without USSR surrendering?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-3, for-the-motherland

Playing as Germany, 1936 scenario.  Russia declared war on me in 1938 and invaded.  It is now 1942 and I've pushed them back to Moscow.  If I take Moscow, Russia immediately surrenders and I "conquer" all of their land.  The land turns grey with red lines, just like when I conquered poland, and all of their armies disappear.

I don't want this to happen, it seems ridiculous.  Is there a way I can change the war so taking Moscow doesn't end it?

I am not afraid to edit the savegame file to change the way the war works, if that is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Go to C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Paradox Interactive\Hearts of Iron III\save games and open your save then search for sov= then search for unity, you should see the russian national unity, and change it to the percent of victory points you want to take before they surrender.
This should do it.

Comment: I don't think changing the game files is a valid strategy.

Comment: @fbueckert - I disagree, it sounds like this is just the way the game mechanics work so there's probably no other way to do it.

Comment: Thanks wvpm.  This sounds like the right answer.  Unfortunately, I've since realized that if I take their capital, their armies can't get any supply anymore since it all comes from the capital.  But it's still a lot better than getting all the land free.